# Expected declaration

Tags: swift, delegate

`delegate`の使い方の練習をしようと思い`playground`で以下のコードを記述したのですが、`test.delegate = self`の行で「`Expected declaration`」というエラーが表示されてしまい、どうすればいいか分からなくなってしまいました。`test.callMethod1()`や`test.callMethod2()`の行でもこのエラーが発生します。どうすればよろしいでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
protocol TestDelegate {
    func delegateMethod1()
    func delegateMethod2()
}

class Test {
    let delegate: TestDelegate!

    func callMethod1() {
        delegate.delegateMethod1()
    }

    func callMethod2() {
        delegate.delegateMethod2()
    }
}

class Swift: TestDelegate {
    let test = Test()
    test.delegate = self

    test.callMethod1()
    test.callMethod2()

    func delegateMethod1() {
        println("this is delegateMethod 1")
    }

    func delegateMethod2() {
        println("this is delegateMethod 2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーの出ている箇所はそこがクラスの中なので、書けるのはインスタンス変数やメソッドの定義など限られたものだけだからです。そこに処理をなんでも書けるわけではないです。

```
class Swift: TestDelegate {
    let test = Test() // これはインスタンス変数（定数）の定義なのでOK
    test.delegate = self // これは手続きなのでダメ

    test.callMethod1() // 同上
    test.callMethod2() // 同上
```

直し方はいくつかありますが、例えば次のように、処理を書いているところをメソッドにして、そのメソッドを改めてクラスの外で呼び出すようにすると、おそらく望み通りの動作になるかと思います。

```
class Swift: TestDelegate {

    func testMethod() {
        let test = Test()
        test.delegate = self

        test.callMethod1()
        test.callMethod2()
    }
```

↑ まず一連の処理を`testMethod()`というメソッドに包む。

```
var swift = Swift()
swift.testMethod()
```

↑ そしてクラスの外で、このように改めてSwiftクラスのインスタンスを作って`testMethod()`を呼び出します。

あと、下の`let delegate`の変数は`let`だと再代入できないので、`var`で変数として定義する必要があります。

```
let delegate: TestDelegate!
```

上記の修正を加えた全部のコードは下記になります。

```
protocol TestDelegate {
    func delegateMethod1()
    func delegateMethod2()
}

class Test {
    var delegate: TestDelegate!

    func callMethod1() {
        delegate.delegateMethod1()
    }

    func callMethod2() {
        delegate.delegateMethod2()
    }
}

class Swift: TestDelegate {

    func testMethod() {
        let test = Test()
        test.delegate = self

        test.callMethod1()
        test.callMethod2()
    }

    func delegateMethod1() {
        println("this is delegateMethod 1")
    }

    func delegateMethod2() {
        println("this is delegateMethod 2")
    }
}

var swift = Swift()
swift.testMethod()
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示いただいたように外からtestMethod()を呼ぶことでうまくいきました。あと、test.delegate = selfでエラーが出ていたので、その疑問も一緒に解決できてよかったです。一つ一つ詳細に解説していただき、大変感謝しております。誠にありがとうございました。